# How to find logos on a website screenshot

Tags: computer-vision, image-recognition

I'm looking for a way to check if a given logo appears on a screenshot of a webpage. So basically, I need to be able to find a small predefined image on a larger image that may or may not contain the smaller image. A match could be of a different scale, somewhat different colors. I need to judge occurrence similarity as well. Need some pointers for what to look at, I've never worked with computer vision before.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest yet not simple way to do it is a normal CNN trained on augmented dataset of the logos.
Trying to keep the answer short, Just make a cnn in tensorflow and train your model on tons images of logos with labels on each training image, It's a simple task and a not-very-crafty CNN must be able to get your work done.
CNN- Convolutional Neural Network

Reference : https://etasr.com/index.php/ETASR/article/view/3919

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. I don't need to find occurrences of a huge number of logos. I basically have up to 10 images and I need to check their usage.

Comment: if you have just 10 images and you want to just do it, the best approach would be to do it manually.